# Making a sticky navigation

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I am using the following jquery and css to stick my nav menu to the top on scroll. The issue is that my nav menu sits under a 100vh div. 
The jquery will not accept vh as a height measure. Any suggestions on how to make it vh?

```js
$(function(){
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 290) {
                $('nav.stickynav').addClass('stickytop');
            }
            else {
                $('nav.stickynav').removeClass('stickytop');
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
.stickynav.stickytop {
        position:fixed;
        top:0
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header class="group">
     <img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>/img/es.png">
     <nav class="stickynav"><?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?></nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: Well you can always calculate the ***px*** value if if you really need to use the viewport size for this: ***1 vh = 1/100th of the height of the viewport.*** and ***$( window ).height()*** will give you browsers viewport.

Comment: `100vh` is equivalent to window height. Try replacing your `290` with `$(window).height()`

Answer (score 0):

css recently introduced position: sticky; i think it would be helpfull for your site since you do not need to use any javascript to get it working. But because of how new it is it will not work on all browsers and not work on not updated browsers (many people use older browsers)

Answer (score -1):

This is the code for the sticker header on my website.. Hope it helps

```js
$(function() {
  /* Sticky Header */
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var sticky = $('.header'),
    scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 100){
      sticky.addClass('fixed');
      sticky.fadeIn();
    } else {
      sticky.removeClass('fixed');
      sticky.removeAttr("style");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* Header */

header.header {
  background: #000;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header.header.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  display:none;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 202;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="main-menu" id="mm">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" title="#">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Please keep in mind, if using this technique, that performing changes when scrolling is bad for performance and might cause scroll jank. To improve performance, you could use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

Comment: @mateBoy I've not noticed any performance issues .. but appreciate your input, I'll have look into your suggested technique. :)

Answer (score -2):

Yo can use one of these libs: https://github.com/jbutko/stickyNavbar.js or https://github.com/leafo/sticky-kit